# RaspberryPi, collectd python plugin, rrd, CGP based occupancy logging/sensing (PIR & Sound)

Tags: python, plugins, collectd

I've got a PIR and a sound sensor working on my Pi ZeroW.
I also have a python script that opens a listening socket and handles the 'sound' or 'motion' interrupts. For each sound/motion event it increments a value which can be read over the socket connection and gets reset to zero after a successful read.

I have created 2 collectd python plugins 'motion.py' and 'sound.py' and they are creating rrd data and graphs in CGP (collectd graph panel) but they are two separate plugins. What I'd really like it to have:

1. A stacked graph showing the two variables summed together (memory usage style)
2. A line graph showing both variables but not summed (load style)

and for both to have them updating once per minute (instead of every 10 secs).

What I have so far is as follows:

I've defined a type 'occupation' in ~/collectd/types.db.local and in ~/cgp/inc/types.db

```
...
occupation              motion:GAUGE:0:U, sound:GAUGE:0:U
motion                  value:GAUGE:0:U
sound                   value:GAUGE:0:U
...
```

In ~/cgp/plugin I have occupation.json

```
{
    "occupation": {
        "title": "Occupancy on {{HOST}}",
        "vertical": "Events",
        "type": "stacked",
        "legend": {
            "motion": {
                "name": "Motion",
                "color": "0000f0"
            },
            "sound": {
                "name": "Sound",
                "color": "ff00f0"
            }
        },
        "legend_format": "%.1lf"    
    }
}
```

and my occupation.py plugin is as follows:

/usr/share/pi/occupation/bin/occupation.py

```
import collectd
import socket
import sys

server_name = 'localhost'
server_port = 10000

def config_func(config):
    collectd.info('config called')

def read_occupation():
    collectd.info('read_occupation called')
    # Read raw value
    # Create a TCP/IP socket
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    global server_name
    global server_port

    server_address = (server_name, server_port)
    sock.connect(server_address)

    sock.sendall('MOVEMENT')
    motion = sock.recv(16)
    sock.sendall('SOUND')
    sound = sock.recv(16)
    sock.close()

    # Dispatch value to collectd
    val1 = collectd.Values()

    val1.plugin = 'occupation'
    val1.type = 'occupation'
    val1.values = [motion, sound]
    val1.dispatch()

    collectd.info('read_motion %s read_sound %s' % (motion, sound))

def init_func():
    collectd.info('init called')


collectd.register_config(config_func)
collectd.register_init(init_func)
collectd.register_read(read_occupation, 60)
```

Using this configuration I get an ERROR: No DS called 'value' (which comes from Base.class.php) because my rrd only has values 'motion' and 'sound' in it - no 'value' value.

I feel I'm close but I'm just making guesses as I don't really understand the limited documentation for the Python Plugin and haven't found anything much better yet.

I found this link https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/106897/collectd.register_read which makes me think I'm going about the python plugin all wrong anyway.

I'm assuming that I'm writing the rrd file correctly but I don't seem to be able to get the graphing part in cgp working correctly. Can anyone show where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance!